# Conda dlip:UnsatisfiableError during installation on Windows 10 using conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, dlib, installation-package

I'm setting anaconda using python 3.6. I want to install dlib package. When I run ;
    #conda install -c menpo dlib 
I have  had :

```
#Solving environment: failed
#UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in  
conflict:
#- backports.os
#- dlib
#  - typed-ast
```

Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

I also tried to remove all the packages which are list on the conflicts and re-run the installation comment but didnt work :/ Any idea?

Comment: I assume you are trying to install into the root environment. Have you tried creating a new environment with `dlib` first, and then installing any other packages you want to use into that environment?

Comment: Thanks @nekomatic  It works :) but not sure how many times I created new environment